# What creates this swooshing guitar effect?

Tags: electric-guitar, guitar-effects

Hillel Slovak in Special Secret Song Inside by Red Hot Chili Peppers at 2:33

creates a quick sound effect with his guitar that sounds like some effect put on feedback being panned rapidly.

How is that sound created? From what I know about making feedback, it takes a second to get started, and it wouldn't fade that nicely either.

I think this might be another example with Jimi Hendrix playing Wild Thing at Monterey: https://vimeo.com/220996511#t=98s, which also resembles one of the many effects on Exp off of Axis: Bold as Love at 1:15 (couldn't find link).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a guitar, bridge pickup, lots of distortion playing high F and C on the 1st and 2nd strings 13th fret being dive bombed with a whammy bar and at the same time panned hard left to right...but hey, I could be wrong.

Comment: Nice ear! I broke out my Wal-Mart guitar that has a whammy, distorted it as much as possible, and it sounded pretty close!

Comment: @bearacuda13 Great, now turn your head quickly from one side to the other for the panning effect, lol!